# How to reset a bootstrap modal after submitting the form in jquery?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I want to reset bootstrap modal after in finishes ajax request in my application. How to load fresh modal after submitting a modal previously?

I have tried removeData() and .modal('dispose') but none of them are working.

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e)
{ 
    $(".modal-body").html("");
});
```

If I am submitting a data and closing the modal it stays on that page which is fine but when I reopen the modal it should come fresh as it came before submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to reset a form in the modal you could do:

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
  $(".modal-body form")[0].reset();
});
```

Comment: I just want to load a modal fresh as new when the modal processed previously. Thanks for the help but this doesn't works in my case.

Comment: Store a clone of the content then and replace with clone each time